# How to hide legend label if chart has no data to show?

Tags: c#, mschart

I have a chart created from the data in my database. If the data which I fetch from the database is null, then the chart won't be shown, but the legend is still visible. How can I hide the legend label if the chart has no data?

```
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter Adapt = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT column_name1,
sum (column_name2) as mySum FROM table 
WHERE YEAR(date_column) = 2019 group by column_name1", conn);
 chart.Fill(ds);
chart.DataSource = ds;
chart.Series["Sum"].XValueMember = "column_name1"; 
chart.Series["Sum"].YValueMembers = "mySum";
chart.Series["Sum"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
conn.Close();
```

Comment: which chart are you using? and if you could show some piece of your code, it will be more clear.

Comment: i used bar chart

Comment: `chart.Series["Sum"].IsVisibleInLegend = somebool` e.g. `bool somebool = chart.Series["Sum"].Points.Count > 0;`